# Istanbul ignore next also ignores jsdoc

Tags: javascript, jestjs, jsdoc

I have a scenario where I have a function which we don't want to include in Jest test coverage but we do still want to include it in JSDoc documentation generation. Take the following function for example:

```
/**
 * This is a test function description
 * @function
 */
/* istanbul ignore next */
export const myTestFunction = () => {
    console.log("testing");
    return true;
};
```

I want that function not to be included in Jest code coverage stats but I do still want that JSDoc to be processed and included in the documentation generated via JSDoc. Adding the istanbul comment seems to cause the function to be ignored for both. Is there an alternate way to tell Jest to exclude this method?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is the JSDoc block is not right above the function (export const) and the comment line is there.  Not sure your real world scenario here to try to suggest a work around.  One option is to put these types of functions into a separate file and add that file to the Jest configuration for collectCoverageFrom, with a negative file in the glob.

```
collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/**/*.ts',
    '!<rootDir>/**/newfunctions.ts',   // This is the file you moved the functions into
    '!<rootDir>/**/*.module.ts'
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, and maybe this didn't work three years ago, but I found simply swapping the comments works.

```js
/* istanbul ignore next */
/**
 * This is a test function description
 * @function
 */
export const myTestFunction = () => {
    console.log("testing");
    return true;
};
```